# Can I toggle a bash file over an Apache server?

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a small bash file on my raspberry pi computer that is also running a small Apache server. The batch file looks like this:

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 10000 ];
 do 
  DOES STUFF HERE
  x=$(( $x + 1))
  sleep 2;
done
```

I want to have buttons on the website that allow me to start (and see if running) or stop a bash file. This would be the equivalent of the console `"bash myfile.sh"` command and pressing ^C to stop it.

Also, being able to customize the values in the bash file would be great such as adjusting the amount of loops or the duration of the "sleep"

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a nifty function called [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
exec("sh mybash.sh");
```

Comment: So could I create one bash script to kill the other one for a "stop" button?

Comment: Why would your script need to be killed? Why would you not want it to finish running?

Comment: Well, It might be practical for it to run on forever, with no limit on executions.

Comment: Then yes, I assume it would be okay to have another `exec` function to kill the script. You could also look into using `screen` for long lived processes, and this will free up on of your `apache2` cores.

Comment: Where can I find 'screen' documentation?